# An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "" does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, command-line-interface

I am using the terminal to copy a file from an s3 bucket to my local machine but I keep getting the error:

```
fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "file_000" does not exist
```

I am using the command:

```
usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp s3://{bucket}/file_000 /Users/user/Documents/Docs/dir/new_file.csv
```

I know the file exists using:

`aws s3 ls s3://{bucket} --recursive --human-readable`

and shows up as:

`2022-08-04 15:53:12   21.2 MiB  file_000`

I have tried adding `--recursive` to the end of the command. The command goes through but then creates an empty directory named `new_file.csv`

Is there anything I can do to solve this?

Comment: How did you list the files?

Comment: I added it into the post

Comment: Try using `aws s3api list-objects --bucket example-bucket --query Contents[].Key` to verify there are no special characters, for instance, keep an eye out for trailing spaces in the key name.

Comment: Thanks @AnonCoward, this helped to see my file was listed as " file_000".  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I ran into this same problem, what worked for me was going back to the s3 bucket and confirming the name of the object in the bucket is the same as inside of my code. I realized that it wasn't and once I corrected that and re-ran the program everything worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone, who will ran into this problem lately, it could happen, when you are trying to copy files **from folder**.

Imagine, I have a large folder with thousand of files, and I want to copy just small amount of file to another folder. In that case if I have s3 path `s3://object1/object2/` where `object2` is folder, I need to add `--recursive` flag to mine request.

And the whole CLI command will be:

```bash
aws s3 cp "s3://object1/object2/" "s3://object1/object3/" --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.jpg"
```

P.S. This is not the only one solution for the "Key '' does not exist" problem, and you might want to debug it further: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/404-error-nosuchkey-s3

Answer (score 1):

I came across this issue when I was trying to access one file from s3, it turns out I was requesting a file that does not exist! Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue. I tried switching the user from root to ec2-user and it worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In case of python users using boto3 this error arises when calling `s3.head_object`, In my case I was using `s3.get_object` also which raises `NoSuchKey` error. If you want to handle both at once you can use/modify the below code.

```
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
import boto3


try:
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
    s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=file_key)
except ClientError as e:
    if e.response['Error']['Code'] == '404' or e.response['Error']['Code'] == 'NoSuchKey':
    # missing file logic
else:
    raise e # or whatever you want
```